# Benders Decomposition Type of Optimality Cut

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, operations-research, mixed-integer-programming

In Bender's decomposition we use optimality cuts.

An optimality cut is $\pi^T (h-Bx)\leq\phi$ or 
$b^Ty'+\pi^T (x-\hat x)\leq\phi$, depending on the subproblem.

I read in the book that both cuts have the same effect. Why? Is there any proof?

For more explanation:

First the master problem is solved, which provides us with a solution vector and lower bound. We then use this vector to construct a subproblem. For a minimization problem, subproblems give an upper bound. If the upper bound is strictly greater than the lower bound, then we add a Bender's cut to remove this point.

We want to solve the below problem by Bender's method:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\min &\; c^Tx + b^Ty\\
\text{s.t.} & \; Ax  \ge d\\
& \; Bx +Dy \ge h\\
& \; y\ge0,\ x\in\mathbb{X}
\end{split}
\label{OP}
\end{equation}

The master and subproblems are:

Master Problem

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\min &\; c^Tx + \phi\\
\text{s.t.} & \;Ax  \ge d\\
& \;  x\in\mathbb{X}
\end{split}
\label{OP1}
\end{equation}

Subproblem:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\min &\; b^Ty \\
\text{s.t.} &\;  Dy \ge h- B\hat x\\
& \;y\ge0
\end{split}
\label{OP3}
\end{equation}
where $ \hat x$ is a solution obtained from master problem that is fixed in the subproblem.

We use this optimality cut if the upper bound is strictly greater than the lower bound:
$$ \pi^T (h-Bx)\leq\phi, $$
where $\pi$ is an optimal solution for the dual of the subproblem.

Now suppose the subproblem is instead

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\min &\; b^Ty \\
\text{s.t.} &\;  Dy \ge h- B x\\
&\;  x= \hat x\\
& \;y\ge0 \\
& \;x\ge0
\end{split}
\label{OP7}
\end{equation}

Then the optimality cut  is $b^Ty'+\pi^T (x-\hat x)\leq\phi$ , where $y'$  and $\pi$ are optimal solutions obtained from the subproblem. Why are the two cuts equal?

Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, which book are you using?

Comment: @David M. "stochastic programing by chung:" booklet

Comment: @David M. Can there be a connection between the shadow price and the cut?

Comment: Is that a textbook? Can you provide a link?

Comment: @David M. Hi , no unfortunately  not , and the language of this book is not English too

Comment: @David M. Hi , I think , The sub problem is solved to estimate$ ϕ $, and in optimality we have $b^Ty=π^T(h−Bx)=\phi$ so if sub problem cant estimate the value $\phi$  correctly (If the upper bound is strictly greater than the lower bound) we use $π^T (h−Bx)<=ϕ $. now in other sub problem if we only use $π^T (x− \hat x) $for optimality cut , this cut Does not estimate the amount of $ϕ$  And we have to add $b^Ty $. till $ϕ $estimated . Do you think I think right?